Transfer my Flutter Web application to the second monitor of devices with 2 monitors
I want to transfer my Flutter Web application to the second monitor of devices with 2 monitors when a button is pressed. Before making it fullscreen with the fullscreen_window package, I need to place my web application on the second monitor. How can I do this?
I tried to do this with JavaScript commands but couldn't succeed.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
